# Simulation Nodes: How to draw curve and have it update to screen immediately while playing timeline?

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

Simon Thommes made this freely downloadable smoke cloud curve drawing asset: https://studio.blender.org/films/wing-it/?asset=6834

[image]

It uses the Simulation Zone in Geometry Nodes.

How can I make even a 'curve to mesh' line appear when I'm playing the timeline and drawing curves in edit mode?

I tried to reduce the Simon's curve setup down and also start from scratch with the Simulation Zone but couldn't understand how it works :/

Answer (score 1):

managed to even more carefully analyze Simon's node network and this seems to be the solution:

[image]

[image]

And here's a little more developed but still simple effect made by it:

[image]

[image]

[image]